# Convert string into dataframe of speakers and text

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I would like to convert a string of text from a document into a dataframe with columns for section, speaker, role and text.

My input data is as follows. I have already extracted the list of speakers from another section of the document, and each speaker has the same role throughout the whole document, and the role is listed below the speaker every time they speak. Speakers and roles are text, not just identified by number, in the actual document - I just call them Speaker1 and Role1 for simplicity in this example.

```
all_text = """Section1\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nThis is the text spoken by the first speaker. Sometimes it contains 
the string Speaker1, but when Speaker1 is in the words spoken section it is not on its own line.
Speaker2\nRole2\nNow someone else is talking.
Section2\nSpeaker2\nRole2\nMore words\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nMore words\nSpeaker2\nRole2
People can speak multiple times per section."""

section_list = ["Section1","Section2"]

speaker_list = ["Speaker1","Speaker2"]
```

So all_text looks like this:

```
print(all_text)

Section1
Speaker1
Role1
This is the text spoken by the first speaker. Sometimes it contains 
the string Speaker1, but when Speaker1 is in the words spoken section it is not on its own line.
Speaker2
Role2
Now someone else is talking.
Section2
Speaker2
Role2
More words
Speaker1
Role1
More words
Speaker2
Role2
People can speak multiple times per section.
```

I would like to create the following output dataframe:

```
    Section     Speaker     Role    Text
0   Section1    Speaker1    Role1   This is the text spoken by the first speaker. ...
1   Section1    Speaker2    Role2   Now someone else is talking.
2   Section2    Speaker2    Role2   More Words
3   Section2    Speaker1    Role1   More words
4   Section2    Speaker2    Role2   People can speak multiple times per section.
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

With the data you provided it will be very difficult to fetch the data correctly.

So I had to tweek the data a little by adding Section for each data.

```
import pandas as pd

all_text = """Section1\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nThis is the text spoken by the first speaker. Sometimes it contains the string Speaker1, but when Speaker1 is in the words spoken section it is not on its own line.
Section1\nSpeaker2\nRole2\nNow someone else is talking.
Section2\nSpeaker2\nRole2\nMore words\nSection2\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nMore words\nSection2\nSpeaker2\nRole2
People can speak multiple times per section."""

li = all_text.splitlines()

speaker = []
section = []
role = []
text = []
print(li)
for index, item in enumerate(li):
    cat = index % 4
    print(cat, item)
    if cat == 0:
        section.append(item)
    elif cat == 1:
        speaker.append(item)
    elif cat == 2:
        role.append(item)
    else:
        text.append(item)

data_dict = {"Section": section, "Speaker": speaker, "Role": role, "text": text}

print(speaker, section, role, text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

print(df)
```

I believe this is not the answer you are expecting.

If you do not want to change your data, then we EITHER need:

1. List of Section names. (This can be used to identify if a section has changed when processing the data)

section_list = ["Section1", "Section2",..]

```
import pandas as pd

all_text = """Section1\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nThis is the text spoken by the first speaker. Sometimes it contains the string Speaker1, but when Speaker1 is in the words spoken section it is not on its own line.
Speaker2\nRole2\nNow someone else is talking.
Section2\nSpeaker2\nRole2\nMore words\nSpeaker1\nRole1\nMore words\nSpeaker2\nRole2
People can speak multiple times per section."""

li = all_text.splitlines()
section_list = ["Section1", "Section2", "Section3"]

speaker = []
section = []
role = []
text = []
temp_section = ""
section_list = ["Section1", "Section2", "Section3"]
for index, item in enumerate(li):
    cat = index % 4
    print(temp_section, "*", index, "*", item)

    if cat == 0 and item not in section_list:
        li.insert(index, temp_section)
        section.append(temp_section)
        continue

    if cat == 0:
        section.append(item)
        temp_section = item
    elif cat == 1:
        speaker.append(item)
    elif cat == 2:
        role.append(item)
    else:
        text.append(item)

data_dict = {"Section": section, "Speaker": speaker, "Role": role, "text": text}

print(speaker, section, role, text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

print(df)
```

OR
2. We need number of rows you gonna have for each section.(also to identify change of section)

Count_section = {
"Section1": 2,
"Section2":3,...
}

Comment: Thank you! I do have section labels from the beginning, so I think item (1) from the end of your question is satisfied, unless I misunderstand what you are saying. I won't know ahead of time the number of rows for each section, so (2) I don't think I can get from the data.

Comment: @Nathan added code with exact data as yours and having section list before hand.